# IP camera keeps dropping frames

Tags: opencv, rtp

I am using an ethernet camera in opencv but I repeatedly get the following warning message when I run my program.

```
[rtp @ 0x1a9c720] Received packet without a start chunk; dropping frame.
```

I think the problem might be with the rtp url I am using:

```
vcap.open("rtp://192.168.40.90:50004/");
```

I'm not even sure if I should be using rtp or something else.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    VideoCapture vcap;


    vcap.open("rtp://192.168.40.90:50004/"); // open IP cam


    int numberOfFrames = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        vcap >> frame;
        cout << "number of frames = " << ++numberOfFrames << endl;
        imshow( "display", frame );

        char c = (char)waitKey(1);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
    vcap.release();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `rtsp` with TCP connection instead of `rtp`. Like this: `rtsp://192.168.40.90:50004/?tcp`.

Comment: Just tried it but that doesn't work. I got this error: [tcp @ 0x26068a0] Connection to tcp://192.168.40.90:50004?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused

Comment: Hi @GuiltySpark did you solve this issue ?

Comment: No, never solved it